# What is the difference between a group and a term set in managed metadata services?

Tags: taxonomy, managed-metadata

I think primarily your most top level item will always be a group.

Once you have a group established you need to add term sets.

So it seems 1 group : (many) term sets (children).

What is the difference between a group and a term set?

While on the subject, is it possible to nest term sets? From the click and point GUI management in central admin it seems that the structure is like this:

```
GROUP
      TERM SET
             TERM
             TERM
                  TERM
```

and not

```
GROUP
      TERM SET
         TERM
         TERM SET
              TERM
```

Comment: Don't think you can nest term sets, just tried it on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but I believe it's something to do with delegation of administration and user permissions- you can apply security restrictions to groups, and each group can have "groups of terms", aka Term Sets.

Comment: I think you're right, its definitely about permissions and not structure per say.

Comment: This post confirms this : http://www.cmswire.com/cms/document-management/sharepoint-2010-administer-taxonomy-using-term-store-management-007525.php

Comment: Good find on that blog post!